# Small aloe watering help

Tags: plant-health, watering, plant-care, aloe

So I have a semi-small aloe and it was neglected for a while but I was able to bring it back. I'm going away for two weeks and want o know if my aloe stands a chance. ( if it helps at all its growing baby's)

Answer (score 2):

Aloe should be completely OK for two weeks without water. Just don’t leave it in direct sun and don’t put the pot into water (like it works for some non-succulent plants).